# how to add directory inside this power shell script

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, batch, batch-file

```
<# copy desktop.ini recursively #> 
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory| foreach { copy "D:\Programs\Media\Media Manager\Filebot\cmdlets\desktop.ini" $_.FullName}

<# set folder attribute readonly recursively #> 
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory| foreach {$_.Attributes = 'readonly'}

<# set attribute readonly for desktop.ini recursively #> 
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -include *.ini| foreach {$_.Attributes = 'readonly,hidden'}

<# set attribute hidden for folder.ico recursively #> 
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -include *.ico| foreach {$_.Attributes = 'hidden'}
```

This powershell script will

1. Add desktop.ini in each subfolder
2. Set some attributes

It works as intented if I excute the script inside a .bat file along other things

```
 powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -Command "D:\Programs\Media\'Media Manager'\c.ps1"
```

### **THE PROBLEM**

I want to add the folders where this script should works, either to the .ps1 or in the .bat whatever possible

For example `D:\folder one` & `D:\folder two`

Comment: applying the code to existing folders.
i haven't mentioned creating any new directory !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your script currently applies to all folders below whatever the current directory is:

```
# the path is implied
Get-ChildItem -Path ./ -Recurse -Directory
```

You could choose to specify a particular folder a few different ways:

```
# A. set your working directory first, then run your script normally. Repeat for each new folder
Set-Location "D:\folder one"
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory | ... # Rest of script


# B. specify the folder in Get-ChildItem:
Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\folder one" -Recurse -Directory | ... 


# C. for many folders, try something like this, with a comma-separated list:
Foreach ($folder in "D:\folder one","D:\folder two") {
  Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Recurse -Directory | ...
}
```

For option B+C, make sure to specify `-Path` in each `Get-ChildItem` command in your script, and you should be good

Comment: brilliant!. options A & B worked. Thanks so much!. for C , i guess the foreach expression outside foreach expression was too much to handle as it failed

Answer (score 0):

To specify multiple target directories, you can specify a string array for the `-Path`parammeter of `Get-CHildItem`:

```
<# Create a string array by spliting a here-string -- avoids typing
multiple quotation marks and delimiters and simplifies subsequent
editing.
#>
$TargetDirs = @'
D:\folder one
D:\folder two
' -split "`n"
```

Then, in your processing:

- `Copy-Item` can use the `-Passthru` parameter to give you immediate access to the newly copied file to set its `Hidden` attribute.
- The other attribute manipulation can also be performed in the same loop.

```
$iniSource   = 'D:\Programs\Media\Media Manager\Filebot\cmdlets\desktop.ini'

$TargetDirs = @'
D:\folder one
D:\folder two
' -split "`n"

Get-ChildItem $TargetDirs -Recurse -Directory| foreach {
    (copy $iniSource $_.FullName -PassThru).Attributes = 'ReadONly,Hidden'
    $_.Attributes = 'readonly'
    Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -FIlter *.ico | foreach {$_.Attributes = 'hidden'}
}
```